# Dynamically execute query using the output of another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, plpgsql, lateral

I have a function called generate_table, that takes 2 input parameters (`rundate::date` and `branch::varchar`)

Now I am trying to work on a second function, using PLPGSQL, that will get a list of all branches and the newest date for each branch and pass this as a parameter to the generate_table function.

The query that I have is this:

```
select max(rundate) as rundate, branch
from t_index_of_imported_files
group by branch
```

and it results on this:

```
rundate;branch 
2014-03-13;branch1
2014-03-12;branch2
2014-03-10;branch3
2014-03-13;branch4
```

and what I need is that the function run something like this

```
select generate_table('2014-03-13';'branch1');
select generate_table('2014-03-12';'branch2');
select generate_table('2014-03-10';'branch3');
select generate_table('2014-03-13';'branch4');
```

I've been reading a lot about PLPGSQL but so far I can only say that I barely know the basics.

I read that one could use a concatenation in order to get all the values together and then use a EXECUTE within the function, but I couldn't make it work properly.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a plain SELECT query using the new [**`LATERAL JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-select.html) in Postgres 9.3+

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT max(rundate) AS rundate, branch
   FROM   t_index_of_imported_files
   GROUP  BY branch
   ) t
 , generate_table(t.rundate, t.branch) g;  -- LATERAL is implicit here
```

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-select.html)

> `LATERAL` can also precede a function-call `FROM` item, but in this
>   case it is a noise word, because the function expression can refer to
>   earlier `FROM` items in any case.

The same is possible in older versions by expanding rows for set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list, but the new syntax with `LATERAL` is much cleaner. Anyway, for Postgres 9.2 or older:

```
SELECT generate_table(max(rundate), branch)
FROM   t_index_of_imported_files
GROUP  BY branch;
```

Comment: Wow! Much simpler than I thought! Thanks a lot for all who answered!

Answer (score 0):

```
select generate_table(max(rundate) as rundate, branch)
from t_index_of_imported_files
group by branch
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything too fancy.

```
SELECT generate_table(rundate,branch) FROM (
    SELECT max(rundate) AS rundate, branch
    FROM t_index_of_imported_files
    GROUP BY branch) x;
```

Comment: Set-returning functions in `SELECT` are deprecated now that `LATERAL` is supported, and can have weird and surprising results.