# How to convert PostgreSQL 9.4's jsonb type to float

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, jsonb, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying the following query:

```
SELECT (json_data->'position'->'lat') + 1.0 AS lat FROM updates LIMIT 5;
```

(The +1.0 is just there to force conversion to float.  My actual queries are far more complex, this query is just a test case for the problem.)

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb + numeric
```

If I add in explicit casting:

```
SELECT (json_data->'position'->'lat')::float + 1.0 AS lat FROM updates LIMIT 5;
```

the error becomes:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb + double precesion
```

I understand that most jsonb values cannot be cast into floats, but in this case I know that the lats are all JSON numbers.

Is there a function which casts jsonb values to floats (or return NULLs for the uncastable)?

Comment: There are no `try_cast` function by default in postgres. You need to write them yourself.

Comment: Related: [How to convert Postgres json(b) to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20236421/1048572), [to text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27215216/1048572), [to boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33041617/1048572)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

There are two operations to get value from `JSON`. The first one `->` will return `JSON`. The second one `->>` will return text.

Details: [JSON Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Try

```
SELECT (json_data->'position'->>'lat')::float + 1.0 AS lat
FROM updates
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: probably you don't want to mess with value so use ::float + 0.0 AS lat, 1 lat change is very big difference !!

Comment: why do I need to add 0.0 (or 1.0 in your case), isn't it already typcasted into a float using ::float?

Comment: Please correct to "direct cast" on pg12.3+ as showed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/62621483/287948

Comment: works flawlessly for accessing inner elements

Answer (score 18):

AFAIK there's no json->float casting in Postgres, so you could try an explicit `(json_data->'position'->'lat')::text::float` cast

Comment: On pg12.3+ you can do "direct cast", as showed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/62621483/287948

Answer (score 13):

### Now we can do it!

In nowadays we can cast directly from JSONb to SQL datatypes. I am using PostgreSQL **v12.3**, where it is working fine:

```sql
SELECT (j->'i')::int, (j->>'i')::int, (j->'f')::float, (j->>'f')::float
FROM  (SELECT '{"i":123,"f":12.34}'::jsonb) t(j);
```

---

Sub-questions:

- *From which version is it possible?*
- *It is a syntax sugar or a [real conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62558306/287948)?*
- *If real "binary JSONb → binary SQL" conversion, where the micro-optimizations?*
   For example, what wold be faster (?) tham "binary JSONb → string → binary SQL"? boolean→boolean, number→numeric, number→int, number→bigint; number→flloat, number→double.
- *Why not optimized for NULL?* 
  Curiosily the "NULL to SqlType" not works, "ERROR: cannot cast jsonb null to type integer".

---

### Benchmark suggestion

How to check?  When PostgreSQL optimize loop queries?

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT (j->'i')::int, (j->'f')::float       -- bynary to bynary INT and FLOAT
-- EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT (j->>'i')::int, (j->>'f')::float  -- string to bynary INT and FLOAT

-- EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT (j->'i')::numeric, (j->'f')::numeric    -- bynary to bynary NUMERIC
-- EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT (j->>'i')::numeric, (j->>'f')::numeric  -- string to bynary NUMERIC

FROM (
  SELECT (('{"i":'||x||',"f":'||x||'.34}')::jsonb) as j FROM  generate_series(1,599999) g(x)
  -- SELECT (('{"i":123,"f":12.34}')::jsonb) as j FROM  generate_series(1,599999) g(x)
) t;
```

---

### PostgreSQL bug?

Even now, 2021 with version pg13 version... Not make sense to not cast NULLs: the natural is to cast `NULL::int` to integer, but PostgreSQL fail in the automatic cast:

```sql
SELECT (j->'i')::int FROM  (SELECT '{"i":null}'::jsonb) t(j); -- fail
```

results in *"ERROR:  cannot cast jsonb null to type integer"*.

Comment: Seems that the only optimization is with `jsonb_populate_record` (check also `jsonb_to_record` or `jsonb_to_recordset`). See also [this dba discussion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/271249/90651)

Comment: "*cannot cast jsonb null to type integer*" is not a bug. You cannot cast objects or arrays to integers either. Use `NULLIF(j->'i', 'null')::int`, or `(j->>'i')::int`

Comment: @Bergi, I using other point of view. Seems a specification error (not a implementation error), and old-fashioned.  Casting **the item**,  e.g. `x[1]::int` is atomic, is not to cast the complex object. `select NULL::int;` is not an error because **compiler most be friendly**:  so,   `select  (j->'i')::int`  also must be friendly... We are in 2023, the age of the ChatGPT, not the stone Age of compilers: must be friendly.

Answer (score 7):

[Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html), there are also the functions

```
jsonb_populate_record()
jsonb_populate_recordset()
```

Analog to their json twins (present since pg 9.3)

```
json_populate_record()
json_populate_recordset()
```

You need a predefined row type. Either use the row-type of an existing table or define one with `CREATE TYPE`. Or substitute with a temporary table ad hoc:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE x(lat float);
```

Can be a single column or a long list of columns.

Only those columns are filled, where the **name** matches a **key** in the `json` object. The **value** is coerced to the column **type** and has to be compatible or an exception is raised. Other keys are ignored.

```
SELECT lat + 1  -- no need for 1.0, this is float already
FROM   updates u
     , jsonb_populate_record(NULL::x, u.json_data->'position')
LIMIT  5;
```

Using an [implicit `LATERAL JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409986/dynamically-execute-query-using-the-output-of-another-query/22410799#22410799) here.

Similarly, use `jsonb_populate_recordset()` to decompose arrays into multiple rows per entry.

This works the same way in Postgres 9.3 with `json`. There is the added benefit that casting to / from `text` internally is not necessary for numeric data in `jsonb`.

Comment: The advantage of JSONb is the NUMBER and BOOLEAN binary formats, and there is no need for intermediary conversion to *text*.  So,  this answer is the best because remember a good practice: **don't waste your CPU time with intermediary CAST to text!**.  By other hand, unfortunately, *PostgreSQL developers* have  done no  more than that: the only [evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_evidence) about "non-reduntant CAST" in PostgreSQL is when using `jsonb_populate_record` (or recordset). See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/271249/90651

Answer (score 5):

Adding a clarification because this comes up as the top hit for a 'JSONB float conversion' search - note that you need to wrap the JSON conversion in brackets, and *then* apply the '::' casting.

As mentioned above, the correct method is:

```
(json_data #>> '{field}')::float
```

If instead you try this it will fail:

```
json_data #>> '{field}'::float
```

This was the mistake I was making in my code and it took me a while to see it - easy fix once I noticed.

Comment: On pg12.3+ you can do "direct cast", as showed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/62621483/287948 (below)

Answer (score 1):

You must to cast the json value to text and then to float.

Try this:

```
(json_data #>> '{field}')::float
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a view I used CAST:

```
create view mydb.myview as
            select id,
            config->>'version' as version,
            config->>'state' as state,
            config->>'name' as name,
            config->>'internal-name' as internal_name,
            config->>'namespace' as namespace,         
            create_date,
            update_date,
            CAST(config ->> 'version' as double precision) as version_number
            from mydb.mytbl;
```