# Pattern matching on jsonb key/value

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing, gwt-gin, jsonb

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4. My table has a `jsonb` column:

```
CREATE TABLE "PreStage".transaction (
  transaction_id serial NOT NULL,
  transaction jsonb
  CONSTRAINT pk_transaction PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
);

CREATE INDEX idxgin ON "PreStage".transaction USING gin (transaction);
```

I store transactions in terms of key / value in the JSONB column. One of the requirements is to search customer name from the key value, hence I am running a query like:

```
SELECT transaction as data FROM "PreStage".transaction
WHERE  transaction->>('HCP_FST_NM') ilike ('%neer%');
```

What ever I do seems the query doesn't like the GIN index. How can I make the query use a GIN index with case insensitive pattern search?

I tried changing `jsonb` column to text, indexing it using `gin_trgm_ops` then search for required text, then converting the result to `json` and then searching in the required key/value. This approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: All the basics for a decent question are missing: Postgres version, table definition, cardinalities, example data, expected outcome, what you have tried ...

Comment: Erwin please find it updated

Comment: Much better. Please describe what can be in the `jsonb` column and add one or more example values.

Comment: Follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33025890/939860

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default GIN index operator class `jsonb_ops` does not allow full-text pattern matching on a value. Details:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)

The best indexing strategy depends on your complete situation. There are many options. To just cover the one key you presented, you could use a **functional trigram index**. You already tested `gin_trgm_ops`, so you are already familiar with the additional module [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html). For those who are not:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Once the module is installed:

```
CREATE INDEX idxgin ON "PreStage".transaction
USING gin ((transaction->>'HCP_FST_NM') gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then this query is supported:

```
SELECT transaction AS data
FROM   "PreStage".transaction
WHERE  transaction->>'HCP_FST_NM' ILIKE '%neer%';
```

I also removed some unnecessary parentheses.

Depending on unknown details, there are various options to optimize index coverage.

***For instance***, if many rows don't have a key *'HCP_FST_NM'* at all, make that a **partial index** to exclude irrelevant rows and keep the index small:

```
CREATE INDEX idxgin ON "PreStage".transaction
USING gin ((transaction->>'HCP_FST_NM') gin_trgm_ops)
WHERE transaction ? 'HCP_FST_NM';
```

[**`?`** being the `jsonb` containment operator.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)
And add the same predicate to every query that's supposed to use this index:

```
SELECT transaction AS data
FROM   "PreStage".transaction
WHERE  transaction->>'HCP_FST_NM' ILIKE '%neer%'
AND    transaction ? 'HCP_FST_NM';  -- even if that seems redundant.
```

Comment: thank you! how can i use multiple keys while creating index for ex: CREATE INDEX idxgin ON "PreStage".transaction
USING gin ((transaction->>'HCP_FST_NM'),(transaction->>'HCP_LST_NM')  gin_trgm_ops) doesnt work

Comment: @user3832677: Please start a new question. I answered this question as given. Comments are not the place for new question. You can always link to this question for context. Be sure to provide all the necessary information in your new question.