# JSON vs TEXT field to keep a list of values in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

What is the best way to keep the following on Postgres?

```
[{'property':'foo1', 'val': "foo_val"}, {'property': 'foo2', 'val': "foo_val2"}]
```

JSON or Text?

From what I understand JSON is good for nested structure(using ->>). But in this case, its a flat structure. Would it still make sense to keep it as JSON or TEXT. Which will be more easier to query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with `JSON` for non-nested structures anyway. Postgres supports operators to get, compare, delete key/value pairs or entire objects. Please also read further about `JSONB` as it might be better for your use case, especially if you plan on doing database operations on json value and would also like to index specific keys.

You can't simply write a query to match value of a key when you store json as `TEXT`, but you can do that using built in json [operators and functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), and there's many more things you can do with it. As an example you can't retrieve `foo_val2` as a value of some key, because string does not have key-value pairs, it's all text.

What I've learned the hard way is that there's no optimization for containment operator for example `LIKE`, so you will still need to unpack the json to text and then perform a search - [see my question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896150/effectively-searching-through-entire-1-level-nested-jsonb-in-postgres) regarding this topic.

**Summing up**, `JSON` or `JSONB` should be your first choice when dealing with json data because it allows you flexibility you don't have with `TEXT`. Especially if you're planning on doing some work on the database side, or if you will find yourself willing to do so.