# How to index a PostgreSQL JSONB flat text array for fuzzy and right-anchored searches?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

PostgreSQL version: 9.6.

The `events` table has a `visitors` JSONB column:

```
CREATE TABLE events (name VARCHAR(256), visitors JSONB);
```

The `visitors` column contains a "flat" JSON array:

`["John Doe","Frédéric Martin","Daniel Smith",...]`.

The `events` table contains 10 million of rows, each row has between 1 and 20 visitors.

Is it possible to index the values of the array to perform efficient pattern-matching searches:

1. *left anchored*: select events whose visitors match 'John%'
2. *right anchored*: select events whose visitors match '%Doe'
3. *unaccented*: select events whose visitors match 'Frederic%'
4. *case-insensitive*: select events whose visitors match 'john%'

I am aware of the existence of the Postgres trigram extension `gin_trgm_ops` enabling to create indexes for case-insensitive and right-anchored searches, but I can't figure out how to create trigram indexes for the content of "flat" JSON arrays.

I read [Pattern matching on jsonb key/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939560/pattern-matching-on-jsonb-key-value) and [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array) but the solutions provided do not seem to apply to my use case.

Comment: Cast it to `text` and use regular expressions with a trigram index.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe thanks for the suggestion. I already tried to index the whole array as text (`create index events_visitors_trgm_idx on events using GIN ((visitors::text) gin_trgm_ops);`) but we cannot then perform searches such as `select * from events where visitors::text = 'John Doe'` because since the array is a flat text, we have to systematically use the `like '%John Doe%'` operator, which does not fit my use case.

Comment: That's why I suggested regular expressions. Search for `visitors ~ '\mJohn Doe\M'`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things. This regular expression approach works well, it can be considered as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the `jsonb` to `text` and create a trigram index on it:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX ON events USING gin
   ((visitors::text) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then use regular expression searches on the column. For example, to search for `John Doe`, you can use:

```
SELECT ...
FROM events
WHERE visitors::text *~ '\mJohn Doe\M';
```

The trigram index will support this query.