# How to format in PostgreSQL CITEXT variable to a regex to be used for search

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, where-clause

First of all - all credits goes to **Laurenz Albe** answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500586/how-to-index-a-postgresql-jsonb-flat-text-array-for-fuzzy-and-right-anchored-sea)

I hava a JSONB colum where I need to perform a search on the values (exactly as explained in the linked question). I think to get advantage from the answer there and the trigram index. However in the answer the regex which is searched is hardcoded directly `WHERE visitors::text *~ '\mJohn Doe\M';`

My value comes from the front end where the user enters a search string which is named in the postgres function as `search_term`.

If I was to use the answer directly I would have to execute `WHERE visitors::text search_term` which obviously won't work.

My question is how to continue the query so that I can modify the `search_term` variable and get the same effet as the `*~ '\mJohn Doe\M'` in the original post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the variable as the right operand to regexp operator `*~`;

```
WHERE visitors::text *~ '\m' || search_term || '\M'
```