# Using Postgres 9.5 GIN indexes and JSONB

Tags: sql, postgresql, gwt-gin, jsonb

I'm trying to create a Postgres GIN index to speed up the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id serial primary key,
    a jsonb not null
);

insert into foo(a) values
    ('[{"b": "aaa"}, {"b": "ddd"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"b": "aaa"}, {"b": "aaa"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"b": "aaa"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"b": "aaa"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"b": "aaa"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"b": "bbb"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"b": "bbb"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"b": "bbb"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[{"b": "ccc"}]'::jsonb),
    ('[]'::jsonb);

select distinct id from (
    select id, jsonb_array_elements(a)->>'b' as b from foo
) t where t.b = 'aaa'
```

Is such a thing possible in Postgres? I am open to other alternatives as well. Unfortunately, I can't normalize the table, so I'll need to work with the table structure that I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply a GIN index here but it may not be particularly useful:

```
CREATE INDEX find_fast_jsonb_value
ON foo USING GIN (a jsonb_path_ops);
```

Now you still have to search through the arrays for matching key/value pairs. Your query then becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM foo, jsonb_array_elements(a) AS t(b)  -- Implicit LATERAL join
WHERE b @> '{"b": "aaa"}';                 -- Comparing json key/values here
```

This also places the [set-returning-function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) `jsonb_array_elements()` in the `FROM` clause, where it belongs.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the reply. However, I'm receiving two errors from this method:

`ERROR:  index expression cannot return a set`

and 

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "->>"
LINE 27: FROM foo, jsonb_array_elements(a)->>'b' AS t(b) -- Implicit ...`

I wonder, what would be the performance difference of using a btree index, compared to maintaining a manual index using triggers? That might be easier to maintain and extend in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your time. I ended up finding the answer in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb?rq=1

Comment: The query I ended up using was `SELECT DISTINCT id from foo where a @> '[{"b": "aaa"}]'`, which was a bit more efficient

Comment: just a note about [GIN indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING): there are 2 types, and `jsonb_path_ops` from this answer is the non-default one. Both index types have their pros and cons, but `jsonb_path_ops` can basically only be used with the containment operator (`@>`).