# PostgreSQL - selecting JSON rows that have an array with a given element

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table named `data_audit` with a column named `body`, which is of type `json`. Each row contains a value with the following structure:

```
{
  "target": {
    "ids": [
      "ID1",
      "ID2"
    ]
  }
}
```

(I've removed lots of irrelevant fields.)

I want to select all the rows whose `ids` array (which may contain 0, 1 or more strings) includes a particular value.

I've tried various combinations of `::jsonb[]`, `ANY()`, `@>`, `json_array_elements_text()` and more, but to no avail.

What's the simplest, most efficient way to run this query?

This table is not yet in production, so if it would be easier / more efficient if the field were of another type (`jsonb`?), that is potentially an option.

I'm running PostgreSQL 10.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one appropriate way to query something you want.

```
select * FROM data_audit cross join lateral 
json_array_elements_text (body->'target'->'ids')  as j(id)
where j.id ='ID1';
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=42d76f34322069078f5a18336fdbfb49)

Comment: Thanks. Will performance of that query be as horrendous as it looks like it would be?

Comment: @rweiser : Not much. But, if you are truly worried about performance, you may either nomalize your tables by storing those values in different tables/columns or create an Index on the json attribute which is frequently fetched. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076895/7998591)

Comment: What do I gain by the `cross join lateral`? It seems to work just as well if I simply query `... FROM data_audit, json_array_elements_text...`.

Comment: @rweiser : Nothing.. `CROSS JOIN` is the  ANSI-92 syntax and is more verbose. The implicit comma syntax a,b  is outdated and should preferably be avoided https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918601/7998591