# Find rows where value in nested JSON document is greater than INT

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonpath

I'm a total PostgreSQL newbie. But I think it sounds interesting to use json/jsonb in a relational database.

*//just for info: I try to realize it by C# .NET Core WebAPI with Dapper*

I'd like to have a table with a (multidimensional) json column like, for example:

```
 id                                   | data                                                             
 _____________________________________|_________________________________________________________________________________
                                      |                                                                                 
 4BF30FE6-D7DD-480B-8592-DC9676576FEF | { timestamps:{ "created":1578614541, "modified":1578615707 }, "type":"single"}  
 1AC2CD8F-09D0-456C-9FD4-B63E354BD324 | { timestamps:{ "created":1578614676, "modified":1578615921 }, "type":"multiple"}
 50AD2D82-5919-4555-BCC2-B24E0DE24263 | { timestamps:{ "created":1578614552, "modified":1578615784 }, "type":"single"}  
 8C3BE671-17D1-49FD-A891-D5E69FDF7FC2 | { timestamps:{ "created":1578614685, "modified":1578615173 }, "type":"single"}
```

And I want to get all ids which have **data::timestamps.created** greater than 1578614670.

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT id, data FROM table WHERE data::timestamps.created > 1578614670;
```

```
 id                                   | data                                                             
 _____________________________________|_________________________________________________________________________________
                                      |                                                                                 
 1AC2CD8F-09D0-456C-9FD4-B63E354BD324 | { timestamps:{ "created":1578614676, "modified":1578615921 }, "type":"multiple"}
 8C3BE671-17D1-49FD-A891-D5E69FDF7FC2 | { timestamps:{ "created":1578614685, "modified":1578615173 }, "type":"single"}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: I see a plain JSON value with two levels of nesting - that's what you call "multidimensional", right? Your version of Postgres and the actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints) are always instrumental.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant by calling "multidimensional" json collection.
And thank you. Your detailed answer below helps me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To descend multiple levels of nesting the [**`#>>`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) is useful. Then cast the extracted `text` to an appropriate [numeric type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) before comparing.

```
SELECT id, data FROM tbl
WHERE (data #>> '{timestamps,created}')::numeric > 1578614670;
```

Equivalent to:

```
...
WHERE (data -> 'timestamps' ->> 'created')::numeric > 1578614670;
```

`numeric` is the safe bet. If you *know* that all numbers in `created` are smaller than 2^31 or 2^63 you can use `integer` or `bigint` respectively. Your sample shows valid numeric literals, but this has to hold for *all* extracted values.

To make it fast, consider an expression index like Miles suggested, with a cast to the appropriate numeric type - but with proper parentheses.

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_data_created_idx
ON tbl (((data #>> '{timestamps,created}')::numeric)); -- all parentheses required
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL Index on JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075918/postgresql-index-on-json/36076895#36076895)

Everything here works for either type `json` or `jsonb`, all the same in this respect.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4c6941f854ff90763ab58dba656d69a8)* (demonstrating both)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Removed the errors that Erwin pointed out (and upvoted [Erwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675243/11471381)). Leaving the rest of the answer since the other information might be useful.**

The following will do what you ask. Here is the table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
  id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
  data jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

And once you've inserted the data, this will perform the query you want.

```sql
SELECT id, data
FROM "table"
WHERE (data->'timestamps'->>'created')::int8 > 1578614670;
```

This extracts the "created" entry from the [JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) column as text, and then converts to an 8-byte integer (64-bit int). For a sequential scan on a large table, this can be quite slow, so you'll want an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) for it.

```sql
CREATE INDEX created_idx ON "table" ((data->'timestamps'->>'created')::int8);
```

Comment: Embarrasing mistake! And the JSON compatibility error that [Erwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675243/11471381) pointed out.