# Using materialized views to improve jsonb indexing and querying

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb, materialized-views

Having an RDS Postgresql 12.5 and working on a table (`app_events`) with a JSONB column (`metadata`), the JSON data may vary based on the event name, see the structure below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public".app_events (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    event_id text NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    creation_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    creation_time_in_milliseconds bigint NOT NULL,
    metadata jsonb NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

There are default indexes (`btree`) on `event_id` and `name`.

Based on the `name` column we create views to normalize the data from JSON into tabular format, an example is below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "public".charity_created AS
 SELECT app_events.id,
    app_events.event_id,
    app_events.name,
    app_events.creation_time,
    date(app_events.creation_time) AS created_date,
    (app_events.metadata ->> 'aggregateId'::text) AS user_id,
    (app_events.metadata ->> 'url'::text) AS url,
    (app_events.metadata ->> 'name'::text) AS charity_name,
    (app_events.metadata ->> 'about'::text) AS charity_about,
    (app_events.metadata ->> 'country'::text) AS country,
    (app_events.metadata ->> 'category'::text) AS category,
    (app_events.metadata ->> 'currencyCode'::text) AS currencycode,
    (app_events.metadata ->> 'isPayItForwardPartner'::text) AS is_pay_it_forward_partner,
    (app_events.metadata ->> 'isCampaignDonationPartner'::text) AS is_campaign_donation_partner
   FROM public.app_events
  WHERE (app_events.name = 'CharityCreated'::text)
  ORDER BY (date(app_events.creation_time)) DESC;
```

And now you can run queries like the below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM "public".charity_created
WHERE charity_name == 'some_charity_name'
```

In addition, we create joins or unions between views and started noticing latency on reads/queries up to an hour sometimes, no timeouts but returning data can be challenging, definitely a big hit in our reporting team.

The question and knowledge I am looking for are, where can I create (or should create) indexes to improve the read latency; Debating with two findings so far.

1. On the actual JSONB column (`metadata`) doesn't make sense, so maybe a solution is to start creating indexes based on the specific schema per event name like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076895/122769)
2. Create `materialized views` and pay the price to refresh the copy of data (every night) while creating indexes on the materialized views, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27708358/122769)
3. Maybe keep the `views` and create indexes on these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use indexes with expressions like:

```
CREATE INDEX app_events_charity_name_idx ON app_events USING(metadata ->> 'name'::text);
```

This index might be used when the expression is used (exactly) in the query, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM app_events WHERE metadata ->> 'name'::text = 'some charity';
```

This should work with your view as well. But you should check that with `EXPLAIN`.

In newer versions of Postgres there is also the possibility of [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html). Compared to materialized views, these have the advantage that you do not have to worry about updating them.

```
ALTER TABLE app_events ADD charity_name TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (metadata ->> 'name'::text);
```

You can create indexes for these columns as well.

Comment: The first option might be the way to go. We do query the view column though which pretty much is the expression indexed AS column_name, do you think this should work? I don't get the EXPLAIN part.

Comment: I guess I should add NOT NULL on create index; because the JSON schema is always different per event name.

Comment: You should definitely investigate it. Sometimes the optimiser can play unexpected surprises.
How are you going to specify NOT NULL in an index definition? I also don't understand how this relates to the schema.

Comment: I saw that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076895/122769. CREATE INDEX animal_index ON farm (((animal ->> 'cow')::int))
WHERE (animal ->> 'cow') IS NOT NULL;

Comment: This is a partial index. It makes sense if the number of NULLs is large but in general you must include that condition into your queries so that the index is used.