# Tuning Postgres Fulltext search

Tags: json, postgresql, database-design, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

The table is **product**:

```
             Table "public.product"
     Column      |           Type           |
-----------------+--------------------------+
 id              | uuid                     |
 attributes      | jsonb                    |
```

Note that **attributes** is a `jsonb` field. At the moment I have ~5k rows and I am querying it like this:

```
select id, to_tsvector(attributes::text) @@ to_tsquery('22222') from product;
```

This query already takes a couple of seconds to complete and I want to know if there is anything I can do to improve that time, namely indexes or improved query ?

For starting this query returns:

```
                  id                  | found 
--------------------------------------+-------
 a8230602-ff3f-4414-affc-3594abcfa617 | f
 da0c70d5-5108-42ea-941d-123589129feb | f
 24ac417a-466c-465c-b346-4fad7a9ad3d8 | f
 4bee6122-c5d7-4e0c-840e-e04c28888a9a | f
 ce5fe539-bcb2-4cec-9012-b2501df7012e | f
```

Which is undesirable, is there a way to return only the rows that have a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM   product
WHERE  to_tsvector('english', attributes::text) @@ to_tsquery('22222');
```

And create a full text index on the expression:

```
CREATE INDEX textsearch_idx ON product
USING GIN (to_tsvector('english', attributes::text));
```

Index expression and the expression in the query must match.

[Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-tables.html)

***Or*** you *may* be able to use a jsonb GIN index:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)

But that's not going to work if you want to search keys *and* values at once.

You might be better off with a normalized table layout to begin with ...