# Test jsonb array to see if it contains one or more elements?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I have a `user` table with a `data` jsonb column. In that, I have a `cars` array that can have 0-N cars in it.

I'm trying to do a query like this to find if the user's `cars` array contains either Toyota or Mitsubishi, but it's throwing an error

```
await knex('users.record')
    .where('created_at', '>', '2019-05-21')
    .select('data')
    .whereRaw('cars', ['Toyota', 'Mitsubishi']) // this seems wrong
    .returning('*');
```

One example user's `cars` array is `['Toyota', 'Mitsubishi', 'Honda', 'Ford']`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
.whereRaw('cars', ['Toyota', 'Mitsubishi'])
```

with

```
where('cars', 'like','%Toyota%').orWhere('cars', ,like, '%Mitsubishi%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`jsonb` contains operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE  created_at > '2019-05-21'
AND   (data @> '{"cars":["Toyota"]}' OR
       data @> '{"cars":["Mitsubishi"]}');
```

Pure SQL, I am not familiar with knex.
This can be supported with an index. See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to look something like this in Knex (with a little helper function to reduce repetition):

```js
const hasCar = brand => knex.raw(
  `?? @> ?::jsonb`,
  [
    'data',
    JSON.stringify({ cars: [ brand ]})
  ]
)

knex('users.record')
  .where(hasCar('Mitsubishi'))
  .orWhere(hasCar('Toyota'))
```