# Get specific values from a jsonb column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `Customer`

- customerId(int)
- customerName(string)
- customerOrders(jsonB)

`customerOrders` has the below structure:

```
{ 
 "nodeValue":[
   { 
      "key": "key1",
      "value": "value1"
   },
   { 
      "key": "key2",
      "value": "value2"
   },
   { 
      "key": "key3",
      "value": "value3"
   },
   { 
      "key": "key4",
      "value": "value4"
   },
   { 
      "key": "key5",
      "value": "value5"
   }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to get the value of `nodeValue` of the rows `key = 'key3' AND key = 'key4'`.

For example: return the value of 'key3' and 'key4', `WHERE key = 'key3' AND key = 'key4'`.

I am trying to do something like:

```
SELECT value, value 
from public.customers 
where nodeValue.key3 = 'key3' 
  AND nodeValue.key4 = 'key4'
```

Comment: `key = key3 AND Key = Key4` cannot happen. Did you mean OR?

Comment: No, both the conditions should be true.

Comment: A single `key` variable cannot have both the values `'key3'` and `'Key4'` at the same time.

Comment: Did you actually mean something like `key3 = 'value3' AND key4 = 'value4'`?

Comment: Yes, single key can have both the values, as it will be part of a different objects. Like { key = "abs", value = "1"}, {key = "sup", value = "1"}, { key = "may", value = "2"}. I want to query something like: SELECT value, value from customers WHERE key = "abs" AND key = "sup";

Comment: Bergi is absolutely right from what I know

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
with orders as 
(
   select jsonb_array_elements(customerOrders->'nodeValue') as orders
   from customers
) 
select orders->'value' as val 
from orders 
where 
    orders->>'key' = 'key3' 
or  orders->>'key' = 'key4';
```

result:

value1

value2

Please note the use of the operator ->> to get the value as text

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/au4NPnBdvQEyjXGdbcXLES/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am looking for something like :{ key = "abs", value = "1"}, {key = "sup", value = "1"}, { key = "may", value = "2"}. I want to query something like: SELECT value, value from customers WHERE key = "abs" AND key = "sup";
<br/>
Result should have 2 values: 1, 1

Answer (score 2):

> get the value of `nodeValue` of the rows where `key = 'key3' AND key = 'key4'`.

Best use the [`jsonb` "contains" operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```
SELECT customerid, customerOrders->'nodeValue'
FROM   customer
WHERE  customerOrders->'nodeValue' @> '[{"key": "key3"}]'
AND    customerOrders->'nodeValue' @> '[{"key": "key4"}]';
```

To make it ***fast*** for big tables support it with an index. Ideally a `jsonb_path_ops` index:

```
CREATE INDEX customer_nodeValue_idx ON customer
USING gin ((customerOrders->'nodeValue') jsonb_path_ops);  -- parentheses required
```

See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)

The later version of your question is a bit more tricky:

> return the *value* of 'key3' and 'key4'

```
SELECT c.customerid, o.values
FROM   customer c
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT o.ord->>'value'
      FROM   jsonb_array_elements(c.customerOrders->'nodeValue') o(ord)
      WHERE (o.ord->>'key' = 'key3' OR
             o.ord->>'key' = 'key4')
      )
   ) o(values)
WHERE  c.customerOrders->'nodeValue' @> '[{"key": "key3"}]'
AND    c.customerOrders->'nodeValue' @> '[{"key": "key4"}]';
```

First filter qualifying rows like above (with a fast index lookup). Then unnest the JSON document and build your answer in a `LATERAL` subquery. Should be simplest, cleanest and fastest. For the technique, see:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

I added `customerid` to the result of both queries to identify rows. That's optional.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ab58a7b7f926745f27bdba2e7d205cee)* (demonstrating both)

#### Design

You might simplify your bloated JSON layout to something like:

```
'{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5"
}'
```

Or at least:

```
'[
    {
        "key1": "value1"
    },
    {
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
        "key4": "value4"
    },
    {
        "key5": "value5"
    }
]'
```

Would make everything considerably simpler, smaller and faster.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you actually want is

```
SELECT
  (SELECT orders->>'value'
    FROM json_array_elements(customerOrders->'nodeValue') AS orders
    WHERE orders->>'key' = 'key3'
  ) AS value_key3,
  (SELECT orders->>'value'
    FROM json_array_elements(customerOrders->'nodeValue') AS orders
    WHERE orders->>'key' = 'key4'
  ) AS value_key4
FROM public.customers;
```

but really your data structure is not suitable for this purpose. Instead of an array with key-value pairs, use an object that has the keys and values as properties. With that, you could access the result easily with

```
SELECT
  customerOrders->'nodeValue'->>'key3' AS value_key3,
  customerOrders->'nodeValue'->>'key4' AS value_key4
FROM public.customers;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a type (or table)

```
CREATE TYPE key_value_type AS (
    key text,
    value text
);
```

Then you can use [jsonb_populate_recordset](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function

```
SELECT
    r_key1.value AS key1,
    r_key2.value AS key2
FROM
    customers c
    JOIN LATERAL jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::key_value_type, customerOrders -> 'nodeValue') r_key1 
      ON r_key1.key = 'key1'
    JOIN LATERAL jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::key_value_type, customerOrders -> 'nodeValue') r_key2 
      ON r_key2.key = 'key2'
```

Alternatively with `jsonb_to_recordset` function (without creating a type)

```
SELECT
    r_key1.value AS key1,
    r_key2.value AS key2
FROM
    customers c
    JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(customerOrders -> 'nodeValue') AS r_key1 (key text,
        value text) ON r_key1.key = 'key1'
    JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(customerOrders -> 'nodeValue') AS r_key2 (key text,
        value text) ON r_key2.key = 'key2'
```

Here is the result for both alternatives;

```
| key1   | key2   |
| ------ | ------ |
| value1 | value2 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my output can return array of records.