# How do I query a postgresql JSON column that is an array

Tags: json, postgresql, querying

I have a table (named members) that has a JSON column (named collection). The JSON column stores an array of integers.

Example:

```
collection
----------
[1]
[5,4,0]
[9,3,1]
```

How do I query to see if an integer is in that array?

Example: Select all the members that have a 3 in their collection (can be [1] or [1,2,3,4,etc]).

Is it possible?

Comment: The the column type json, or text that is json?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`json` / `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) [**containment operator `@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).
Since your JSON array seems to contain only *numbers*, the simple syntax works:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  collection @> '3';  -- single quotes required!
```

If you omit the quotes, Postgres resolves the *numeric literal* to `integer` and doesn't find an operator for `json @> integer`.
With quotes, the *string literal* is resolved  to `json` / `jsonb` respectively (containing the JSON primitive type *number*) derived from the context, and it works.

This works just as well, and may be preferable:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  collection @> '[3]';
```

Now, the right operand resolves to `json` / `jsonb` containing the JSON primitive type *array* - containing a single *number*.
This also works for *objects* as array element types, which would not work without the array wrapper.

To make this ***fast***, use the type `jsonb` rather than `json` because that enjoys index support. Either with the default operator class `jsonb_ops` (default does not have to be spelled out):

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_jsb_idx ON tbl USING GIN (collection);
```

Or with the more specialized (but also more efficient) operator class  `jsonb_path_ops` (non-default has to be spelled out):

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_jsb_idx ON tbl USING GIN (collection jsonb_path_ops);
```

See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

Answer (score 0):

Use the json operator `@>`, which means “contains”:

```
select 
  collection @> 3 as has_3
```

If your column is text that is json, use `collection::json @> 3`

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I have json array column in second table `["Amarawati", "Amravati","AMRAVATI"]` and Im trying to join with first table varchar column `Amarawati`

Example Query:

```
select a.* from varchar_district a
left join json_array_table_district ddc on 
ddc.fp_district::jsonb @> (concat('["',ba.district,'"]',''))::jsonb
```