# Check if an array contains a value CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, criteria, jsonb

I've been tinkering a bit with criteria builder queries to figure out how to check if an array of **strings** contains a/or many values, but the tricky thing is that this array is inside a **`jsonb`** column called `data`. I don't know how to achieve that using CriteriaBuilder queries. I'll paste my psql script below:

```
SELECT * FROM myScheme.myTable t where t.data->>'categorys' @> '17';
```

I have done something like this with criteria, but it isn't working

```
if (Objects.nonNull(filter.getCategorias())) {
                predicates.add(builder.and(builder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text",
                                String.class,
                                root.get("data"),
                                builder.literal("categorys"))
                        .in(filter.getCategorias())));

        }
```

I tried researching how to implement the contains operator **`@>`** but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `jsonb` "contains" operator [**`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) expects the type `jsonb` to the left. So use the [**`->`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) operator to extract the 'categorys' object as `jsonb` instead of `->>` which returns `text`:

```
SELECT * FROM myScheme.myTable t WHERE t.data -> 'categorys' @> '"17"';
```

But that's just fixing the error. You should really use:

```
SELECT * FROM myScheme.myTable t WHERE t.data @> '{"categorys":["17"]}';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pwublH3-)

This can also tap into an index on the `jsonb` column. See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

**Double quotes** around `"17"` if it's indeed an array of ***strings***. Remove the quotes for numeric data.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge, I'll take it to improve at queries. I really appreciate it. By the way, do you know how to do exactly the same query with Criteria Builder (Java) ?