# How to query jsonb column that is an array of objects?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Postgres db containing a table with a `jsonb` column `tsent` that contains the results of targeted sentiment analysis of text in another column. The data is structured like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl(id int PRIMARY KEY, tsent jsonb);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, '[
    {
        "class": 0,
        "entity": "John Smith",
        "sent_no": 0,
        "class_label": "negative",
        "entity_type": "PER",
        "sentiment_prob": 0.95
    },
    {
        "class": 1,
        "entity": "University of Illinois",
        "sent_no": 0,
        "class_label": "neutral",
        "entity_type": "ORG",
        "sentiment_prob": 0.95
    }
   ]');
```

It is an array of objects because a given text could have more than one entity. I am wondering how to write a query that would retrieve all records that have John Smith as an entity, and also those that have John Smith as an entity and class_label negative for him.

I am still learning jsonb and know how to query for a key being present, but not how to query for a key being present in any element in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that but this is probably the most generic and clear (yet not necessarily the most efficient) -

- Flatten the table with a JSON object into a "regular" table
- do whatever querying you need using this table

Flatten the table (a [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) is insrtumental here):

```sql
 select id, content, t.*
 from tbl,
  lateral jsonb_to_recordset(tsent) as t(
      class integer,
      entity text,
      sent_no integer,
      class_label text,
      entity_type text, 
      sentiment_prob numeric
  );
```

| id | content | class | entity | sent_no | class_label | entity_type | sentiment_prob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 0 | John Smith | 0 | negative | PER | 0.95 |
| 1 |  | 1 | University of Illinois | 0 | neutral | ORG | 0.95 |

Query using the above "flat" table (`t` CTE):

```sql
with t as 
(
 select id, content, t.*
 from tbl,
    lateral jsonb_to_recordset(tsent) as t(
      class integer,
      entity text,
      sent_no integer,
      class_label text,
      entity_type text, 
      sentiment_prob numeric
  )
)
select content, <other expression(s) here>
from t
where <your logic here>;
```

Comment: In that second case, does t just contain the flattened contents of tsent or tbl columns plus t columns? Because what I ultimately want to do is get the text from tbl.content where the entity conditions are met

Comment: No it does not. If you need `tbl.content` then add it to the CTE select list so that `t` will contain it. Answer edited.

Comment: To have all `tbl` columns plus the flattened contents of `tsent` in the CTE just `select * from tbl, lateral ...` in the CTE's body.

Comment: And of course you can implement your select list and "where" logic directly in the first query w/o a CTE. The second one is there only because it is step-by-step illustrative.

Comment: OK tried the first, appending where t.entity = 'John Smith' and it returned zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a Json Path query.**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE tsent @? '$[*] ? (@.entity == "John Smith" && @.class_label == "negative")';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/DxOXutui)

`@?` is an "exists" predicate on the whole JSON object, `@@` retrives the actual values at that path. For more info see [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Comment: When I try that, the query runs but returns zero records for multiple entity and class_label combos that I know exist.

Comment: You would have to give a proper example. Maybe your JSON structure isn't as simple as this?

Answer (score -1):

A plain expression with the [`jsonb` contains operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) does it:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  tsent @> '[{"entity": "John Smith","class_label": "negative"}]';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zub_lQWi)

Can even use index support. See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)