# How to cast / parse JSON string as number / float in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a JSONB column in my Postgres DB. In some cases it contains numbers encoded as strings*, such as:  `"123"` or `"3.232"` or `"2.32e14"`. The quotes are part of the stored JSONB value, it's `"123"` not `123`.

I'd like to sum up these values, thus need a way to treat them as floating point. I cannot find any way in PSQL to do this.

`select column::float` fails since they are JSON strings, not DB text type.  Nor does `column::text::float` work.

`select to_number(column::text, '999.999')` doesn't work since `to_number` requires a fixed format of number and I can't find a way to parse a standard formatted floating point number.

How can I convert the JSONB string-encoded values into a numeric value for computations?

---

**Background: They are stored as strings because storage needs to be exact and does not survive a round-trip to/from a float point. For calculations it's okay to reduce precision to float.  They could survive a round-trip to a high-level decimal format, but it's a limitation of the Python library SQLAlchemy with JSON that prevents this from working. Even if we find a solution here, I still need to migrate existing data, thus the question stands.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert PostgreSQL 9.4's jsonb type to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826385/how-to-convert-postgresql-9-4s-jsonb-type-to-float)

Comment: No, as it deals with a sub-field and misses the specific need to cast the top-level value.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using postgresql 12+, you can use the [`.double()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-OP-TABLE:%7E:text=Approximate%20floating%2Dpoint%20number%20converted%20from%20an%20SQL%2FJSON%20number%20or%20a%20string) jsonpath method for this:

```
WITH d(json) AS (
    VALUES ('"123"'::jsonb)
         , ('"3.232"')
         , ('"2.32e14"')
)
SELECT json, JSONB_TYPEOF(json), jsonb_path_query(json, '$.double()')
FROM d;
```

| json | jsonb_typeof | jsonb_path_query |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | string | 123 |
| 3.232 | string | 3.232 |
| 2.32e14 | string | 232000000000000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

---

Since the `path` here only ever returns a single `double` the `jsonb_path_query_first()` function is more appropriate, as the `jsonb_path_query()` returns a set of result (usually used in a subquery):

```
WITH d(json) AS (
    VALUES ('"123"'::jsonb)
         , ('"3.232"')
         , ('"2.32e14"')
)
SELECT SUM(jsonb_path_query_first(json, '$.double()')::float)
FROM d;
```

| sum |
| --- |
| 232000000000126.22 |

Comment: I'm not sure what type this is returning, but the result does not appear to be usable in a computation such as `sum`.  That is, `select sum(jsonb_path_query(json, '$.double()))` does not work. `aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls`.  So I presume the path function is an aggregate, not a value.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: you're right, the `jsonb_path_query` returns a set and so is not really meant to be used directly in the `SELECT` clause most of the time. I mostly used it to show the `$.double()` jsonpath could work. I added a example using `jsonb_path_query_first()`, which works better here since it returns a single result.

Comment: Ah, okay. I tried the `::float` cast but the `_first` variation of the function was the trick to getting it to work.

Comment: I found an alternate solution as well, see my answer. Do you know which approach might make more sense?

Answer (score 2):

This syntax converts the type to an unescaped JSON value and then casts to a float:

`(value#>>'{}')::float`

For example, in a sum:

```
WITH d(json) AS (
    VALUES ('"123"'::jsonb)
         , ('"3.232"')
         , ('"2.32e14"')
)
SELECT SUM((json#>>'{}')::float)
FROM d;
```

This achieves the same result as the answer from @Marth. I'm uncertain which is the more correct, performant, or preferred approach.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed that "value at current path" (since you could write your query as 
`json#>>(ARRAY[]::text[])` with the array the path to look up) would extract the text value itself and make it castable, but it makes sense. The main difference I see with my answer is the error for non-numeric values (generic cast error e.g "invalid input syntax for type double precision" vs "jsonpath item method .double() can only be applied to a string or numeric value"). I can't say which is faster, though I would guess it's yours. Anyway, good to have a solution for postgresql <12, +1.