# Looking in array with a big set of input values

Tags: arrays, performance, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have a table that looks like (with an example of number of rows in each to get the kind of ration):

expectedreportsnodes (1 000 000 rows):

```
 nodejoinkey   | integer  | not null
 nodeid        | text     | not null
 nodeconfigids | text[]   |
```

`nodeconfigids` array generally contains 1-50 values.

And a second table:

`expectedreports` (10 000 rows):

```
 pkid       | integer  | not null
 nodejoinkey| integer  | not null
 ...
```

I want to query for all expected reports for which their exists a entry in `nodeexpectedreports` with a given `nodeConfigId`. 
I have potentially large amount of `nodeConfigIds` (thousands).

What is most efficient way of doing that?

For now, I have:

```
select E.pkid, E.nodejoinkey from expectedreports E 
inner join (
  select NN.nodejoinkey, NN.nodeid, NN.nodeconfigids from (
    select N.nodejoinkey, N.nodeid, unnest(N.nodeconfigids) as nodeconfigids  
    from expectedreportsnodes N
  ) as NN 
  where NN.nodeconfigids) IN( VALUES ('cf1'), ('cf2'), ..., ('cf1000'), ..., ('cfN')  )
  ) as NNN on E.nodejoinkey = NNN.nodejoinkey;
```

This seems to give the expected results but takes ages to execute.

What can be done to improve the query?

*Updates:*

- the proposed answer with array overlap and indexes is vastly less efficient on my set-up. I'm not able to say why.
- the following version seems to be the quickiest (again, not the least idea why - perhaps because I generally have few values in values in nodeconfigids?):

_

```
select E.pkid, E.nodejoinkey from expectedreports E
inner join (
  select NN.nodejoinkey, NN.nodeconfigids
  from (
    select N.nodejoinkey, N.nodeconfigids, 
           generate_subscripts(N.nodeconfigids,1) as v
    from expectedreportsnodes N
  ) as NN
  where NN.nodeconfigids[v] in(values ('cf1'), ('cf2'), ..., ('cf1000'), ..., ('cfN') )
) as NNN
on E.nodejoinkey = NNN.nodejoinkey
```

Comment: To optimize performance, we generally need more specific data. Consider the [tag info for `[postgresql-performance]`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: BTW, your `IN (VALUES ...)` expression is invalid syntax. You are mixing row and set syntax.

Comment: There is no need for a `values` keyword when using `IN` just use `in ('cf1', 'cf2', ...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I read that it was better with a big number of values: http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks_I#Predicate_IN_optimalization . Is it generally false ? (I will need to bench it, to)

Comment: Interesting, I have never seen that. Worth investigating though

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `IN` doesn't scale well with long lists. I have same related notes in my answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I understand that. But does wrapping the list in a `values` clause really change that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That variant is new for me, too. But the source is good. The author is [Pavel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/406691/pavel-stehule).

Comment: I took the liberty and removed one set of parentheses that would spoil the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to performance is a [**GIN index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/gin.html) on the array column. And work with operators that can use the index.

```
CREATE INDEX ern_gin_idx ON expectedreportsnodes USING gin (nodeconfigids);
```

Query:

```
SELECT e.pkid, nodejoinkey 
FROM   expectedreports e
JOIN   expectedreportsnodes n USING (nodejoinkey)
WHERE  n.nodeconfigids && '{cf1, cf2, ..., cfN}'::text[];
```

This should work just fine for arrays of `text`, because the [overlap operator **`&&`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) is supported by the default GIN operator class. [Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/gin-builtin-opclasses.html):

```
Name        Indexed Data Type  Indexable Operators
...
_text_ops   text[]             && <@ = @>
...
```

Also be sure to have a plain btree index on `expectedreports.nodejoinkey`:

```
CREATE INDEX expectedreports_nodejoinkey_idx ON expectedreports (nodejoinkey);
```

#### Optimize with multicolumn index

To optimize further for the given query, you could include the otherwise not useful column `nodejoinkey` to the index to allow index-only scans.

To include the `integer` column, first install the additional module [**`btree_gin`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gin.html), which provides the necessary GIN operator classes. Run *once per database*:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
```

Then:

```
CREATE INDEX ern_multi_gin_idx ON expectedreportsnodes
USING gin (nodejoinkey, nodeconfigids);
```

Same query.
Related answers with more details:

- [Multicolumn index on 3 fields with heterogenous data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658515/multicolumn-index-on-3-fields-with-heterogenous-data-types/22675324#22675324)
- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)

### Alternative with `unnest()`

If the GIN index isn't an option (or doesn't perform to your expectations) you can still optimize the query.

It's particularly efficient to unnest long input arrays (or use a `VALUES` expression like in your  example) and then **join** to the derived table. An `IN` construct is typically the slowest option.

```
SELECT e.pkid, nodejoinkey
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT n.nodejoinkey 
   FROM  (SELECT nodejoinkey, unnest(nodeconfigids) AS nodeconfigid
          FROM   expectedreportsnodes) n
   JOIN  (VALUES ('cf1'), ('cf2'), ..., ('cfN')) t(nodeconfigid) USING (nodeconfigid)
   ) n
JOIN   expectedreports e USING (nodejoinkey);
```

Modern form in Postgres **9.3+** with an implicit `JOIN LATERAL`:

```
SELECT e.pkid, nodejoinkey
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT n.nodejoinkey 
   FROM  expectedreportsnodes n
       , unnest(n.nodeconfigids) nodeconfigid
   JOIN  unnest('{cf1, cf2, ..., cfN}'::text[]) t(nodeconfigid) USING (nodeconfigid)
   ) n
JOIN   expectedreports e USING (nodejoinkey);
```

- Your original query can produce duplicate rows in the result. Folded with `DISTINCT`.
- Details for `JOIN LATERAL`:

  - [Dynamically execute query using the output of another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409986/dynamically-execute-query-using-the-output-of-another-query/22410799#22410799)

#### For **short input arrays**, an `ANY` construct is faster:

```
SELECT e.pkid, nodejoinkey
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT e.nodejoinkey 
   FROM   expectedreportsnodes e
   JOIN   unnest(e.nodeconfigids) u(nodeconfigid) 
          ON u.nodeconfigid = ANY ('{cf1, cf2, ..., cfN}'::text[])
   ) n
JOIN   expectedreports e USING (nodejoinkey);
```

Comment: Aside: [Postgres 9.4 brought a couple of performance improvements for GIN indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4.html#AEN118991). The current version should be very attractive for you.

Comment: 9.4 brought goodness in many ways... But I'm blocked and must support postgres user installation, from 8.4

Comment: @fanf42: All of the above should work for pg 8.4+, and much faster than without GIN index. Just not quite as efficient as in the current version. I added some alternatives without GIN index, but the GIN index is still the silver bullet.

Comment: Thanks, that definitly helps. I'm going to set-up a new test bench and test them. In all case, the original question is considered answered, since I have all I need to know to test and optimize

Answer (score 1):

The following avoids the unnesting of the array and might be faster:

```
select E.pkid, E.nodejoinkey 
from expectedreports E 
  join expectedreportsnodes nn on E.nodejoinkey = NNN.nodejoinkey
where nn.nodeconfigids && array['cf1', 'cf2', ..., 'cf1000', ..., 'cfN'];
```

It will return rows from `expectedreportsnodes`  where any of the values in the array appear in the `nodeconfigids` column.